# Eigenvalues of product of similar matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Problem: 
"Say we have two similar matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix}9&7\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}10&8\\-2&0\end{bmatrix}$. Now, let $C=C_1C_2 \cdots C_{10}$ where $C_{i}\in\{A,B\}$. Find the eigenvalues of C."

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are:

For A: $\lambda_{1}=8$, $\lambda_{2}=2$ with eigenvectors $v_1=(-7,1)$ and $v_2=(-1,1)$

For B: $\lambda_{1}=8$, $\lambda_{2}=2$ with eigenvectors $v_1=(-4,1)$ and $v_2=(-1,1)$

I'm struggling quite a lot with this question. Can someone give me a hint/information for what direction to move in (not a solution!), or anything that would help me better understand this question? Thank you!

Comment: What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: For A: $\lambda_{1}=8$, $\lambda_{2}=2$ with eigenvectors $v_1=(-7,1)$ and $v_2=(-1,1)$
For B: $\lambda_{1}=8$, $\lambda_{2}=2$ with eigenvectors $v_1=(-4,1)$ and $v_2=(-1,1)$

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I don't see how you can answer this question in general. For instance, $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ &1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ &2\end{bmatrix}$ are similar (and even have distinct eigenvalues), but $A^{10}$ has eigenvalues $2^{10}$ and $1$, while $A^8 B^2$ has eigenvalues $2^8$ and $2^2$.

Comment: You're making a valid point, but I think the ordering of the eigenvalues in the example in this problem does allow one to state an unequivocal answer.  But I may be wrong too.

Comment: Eigenvalues have no natural ordering - what do you mean by 'ordering of the eigenvalues' and how does that show there is an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, knowing that $A$ and $B$ are similar is not enough to determine the eigenvalues of their product $AB$, let alone an $n$-fold product of copies of $A$ and $B$. The only reason this problem is doable is for the very special reason that $A$ and $B$ are two by two matrices and that they share an eigenvector.

Hint:

- Show that $v_2=(-1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $2^{10}$.
- Compute the determinant of $C$.
- Use the fact that you know $\det C$ and one eigenvalue of $C$ to compute the other eigenvalue of $C$.

Comment: Clever! So it seems like the eigenvalues of $C$ are indeed $\lambda_1^10$ and $\lambda_2^10$.